# Java Scalr resize image corrupted file

Tags: java, imgscalr

I'm trying to resize PNG images, convert them to data URL and then download them in frontend.
The whole process works just fine but when I try to open the file (for example) in Photoshop I get "unexpected End of file (EOF)".
This only happens when I resize the image using Scalr. When I convert to data URL without any resizing I don't have any problems.

```
public String designToDataURL(Design design, Integer width, Integer height)
        throws IOException {
    
    URL url = new URL(design.getPreviewUrl());
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(url);
    
    // If I comment this line, everything works quite fine:
    BufferedImage resized = Scalr.resize(bufferedImage, width, height);
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStream b64 = new Base64.OutputStream(os);
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", b64);
    return os.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Using https://www.nayuki.io/page/png-file-chunk-inspector to inspect the PNG chunks.
[image]

Comment: Your example code doesn't actually encode the resized image

Comment: So I used `java.util.Base64` to do the encoding and decoding without issue.  I "think" your issue has more to do with `os.toString("UTF-8");` and the possibility that the stream is already exhausted, but since I don't know what API `OutputStream b64 = new Base64.OutputStream(os);` is coming from, it's impossible to say

Comment: Maybe, you should also be using `b64.toString("UTF-8");` instead (I have no idea) and `b64.flush()` might also help

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh my.. I imported the wrong Base64 Library. When using the correct one, everything works fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you convert to Base64, every aligned block of 3 input bytes become 4 output bytes. Because of this, each input byte partially affects 2 output bytes, so the Base64 encoder cannot generate output bytes on a one-to-one basis; the encoder must buffer some input bytes and write output blocks.

Doing `b64.flush()` will not help due to the partial byte problem. The solution is to do `b64.close()` after all input bytes are finished. This will cause remaining partial bytes to be flushed, and it will append the special Base64 termination bytes.